# GIT GUI client on Windows for Unix GIT installation

Tags: windows, git, version-control, sas, dvcs

Our company programs and runs data analysis on a Linux server.  The programming is done in Windows clients (SAS, generally).  Each project is only programmed by one person and is reviewed by another.

We would like to put our projects under version control but leave the code on the server (ie not pulling to local Windows repositories).  The advantage is incremental backup and helps with confirming changes from the reviewer.

Does anyone know of a Windows client that can read remote repositories but perform GIT actions using GIT on Linux, rather than on Windows?  Trying a few clients (e.g. SourceTree and SmartGIT) suggests only the latter is possible.

Thanks, Rich

Comment: Would you elaborate on the backup and review advantages of the model you're proposing? I'm not sure I follow how a more conventional DVCS workflow doesn't provide them. I'm sceptical that you'll find a client that *can* work exclusively with remote repositories, when local clones are so fundamental to DVCS.

Comment: We're trying to avoid installing GIT on each Windows PC.  Also, we're not allowed to store project code on local PCs.  As we are only working with a remote repository, it's quite slow over a VPN connection to transfer project files to local PC, process in GIT and copy them back to the server (slow in SmartGIT anyway).
Intuitively, doing it all server-side would seem sensible

Comment: There are quite a few points in your comment to go over; would you mind [discussing them in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29915/room-for-question-http-stackoverflow-com-q-16538520-351301)?

Comment: This is what you get for trying to do version control of SAS code...   You're not supposed to know about version control! Your working in SAS! ;-)

Comment: I can only agree.  Not my choice.  I hear they might introduce it themselves before the decade's out...

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to export the directories containing the Git repositories on your server over CIFS (via Samba) and then mount them as network disks on your workstations.

But really I can't understand what's wrong with using Git the normal way.

Deployment is best done using native packages for the target system (hard to do on Windows, I admit) or a `tar.gz` archive (doable using `git archive`) or a tool like [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/git-ftp) or rsync.

If you need code review, consider using [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/).

As to backups, each Git repository clone *is,* in a sense, a set of differential backups of itself.  That is, the more (local) clones you have the safer you are.

Comment: Ah, Gerrit would be great but the perils of mega-corp IT depts means it'll never happen.  I've added a comment in response to @Shambulator which I hope clarifies thing a little. Samba is certainly an option - but wouldn't the GIT processing still happen on the PC, not the server?

Comment: @rambles, there's just no way to do any client-induced Git processing on the server other than which happens during Git protocol exchange (fetch/push operations), and the Git protocol does not provision for any "free-form" commands from the clients. If you *really* need something like this why not just automate this sort of stuff using SSH form the clients or may be writing some specialized CGI (RESTful maybe) application which would accept certain commands from the clients and then call Git on its (the server's) side?

Comment: Crikey, I'm only a SAS programmer!  @shambulator kindly spoke with me in a chatroom earlier (see above) and we concluded that (like yourself) it's not possible and that the best solution we can think of is to use Gitweb for viewing remote repositories and stick to using Putty for the Git commands.  

That said, mega-corp IT dept today told me they do support SVN...